# Remove spacing column begin line

Tags: vimrc

I have an annoying problem that I have no idea how to fix it. Every time I open a specific log file for some weird reason the window starts with 2 spaces column.

[image]

This happen only with this specific log and I have no idea how to remove those columns. The only way that I've found is to rename the file (e.g. foo) and open it. When I do that, the layout is normal. Can anyone help please ?

Cheers,
Stefano.

Comment: Can you try `set foldcolumn=0` in the specific log file? If that removes the column we'll have to figure out why it is set only for this file and see how to unset it.

Comment: It could also be the sign column: `:set signcolumn=no`. As for why this happens with this specific file is hard to say without more information about the file and your Vim setup. You can try following the steps in [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51)

Comment: @statox It was that!!! Thanks a lot, it was driving me crazy.

Comment: @MartinTournoij : I'll try to debug and see why only this specific file.

Comment: Keep us updated but I think we can close this question as a duplicate of "How to debug my vimrc" because it is unlikely that the solution will be useful to another user.